# how to persist tableview data on vertical scroll

Tags: iphone

i have created scrollview and have loaded tableview on that programmatically .also i have created customize tableview cell and displaying data in tableview.But my problem is whenever i am scrolling tableview vertically my data is not getting persist and data of cell is getting erase.Please help me how shuld i store that data

Comment: neel, tableView is subclass of scrollView and as per apple's documentation you should not add tableView on scrollView. please see where you are setting cell.textLabel.text. Might be possible that it is causing problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you might not be using the reuseidentifiers of the table view properly. If you give all cells the same reuseidentifier then as you scroll the cells that go off screen might end up losing the customizations you made to them. I suggest getting a good understanding of reuseidentifiers, you could start here:[iphone-what-are-reuseidentifiers-uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152180/iphone-what-are-reuseidentifiers-uitableviewcell)