# Adding colors to a few cells in a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I've looked at dozens of answers to this problem on this very site but I still can't get it to work. I, like many before me, want to change the color in a few cells in a table view. I tried putting a conditional if (indexPath.row == ...) then change the color of a few cells to red, but this always results in other cells gradually becoming red changing the more I scroll. I tried moving this code from:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To here:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

But this still doesn't work. How can I change the colors of cells, say, 5. 13, and 40 to be red?

Comment: Is the amount of data static or dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem in your cell reuse, that is why you got colours changing when scrolling.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//Cell creation code goes here, including cell re-usage

    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    //This else part is IMPORTANT
    else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

You'll get a better understanding about [Cell Reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152180/iphone-what-are-reuseidentifiers-uitableviewcell) in UITableView

Comment: Thank you, yes, that is definitely the issue but I'm still not sure how I can resolve it the way I want. I ultimately want 3 groups of colors so I may have to do this in a completely different way.

Comment: You can give any number of groups of colour, also consider the ELSE part

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this method..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 5 | indexPath.row == 13 | indexPath.row == 40)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else 
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but this is exactly the code I am using that doesn't work. Other cells begin to turn red as I scroll. If I limit it to one cell turning red, exactly 12 cells later another will be red as I scroll.

Comment: Are you sure for reusable cell. I mean are you using reusable cell?.

Answer (score 0):

If you large number of value you can take in array and put in a condition like

```
if([array containsObject:indexPath.row])
```

Otherwise this is good to give color in cell in `willDisplayCell`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == 5 | indexPath.row == 13 | indexPath.row == 40)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else 
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```