# UITableView cells seems to fly in

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios8

I have weird problem on iOS 8 with dynamically resizing table cells.
While I scroll down table, cells which come in and appear seems to fly in. It looks like cell adjust width to fit iPhone 6 (like stretching from wider size).

How to prevent that strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

read and learn about **reuseIndetifier**, it will speed up cell rendering and a must to use. And post code next time :)

[iPhone - What are reuseIdentifiers (UITableViewCell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152180/iphone-what-are-reuseidentifiers-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I know how to use **reuseIdentifier** and I do it.
Problem is completely different, maybe someone else met that kind of issue.