# What is the purpose of the reuseIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

What is the purpose of the reuseIdentifier in above constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152180/iphone-what-are-reuseidentifiers-uitableviewcell

Comment: As per the Apple's doc - reuseIdentifier is a string used to identify the cell object if it is to be reused for drawing multiple rows of a table view. Pass nil if the cell object is not to be reused. You should use the same reuse identifier for all cells of the same form.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `reuseIdentifier` is used to group together similar rows in an `UITableView`.

A `UITableView` will normally allocate just enough `UITableViewCell` objects to display the content visible in the table.

If `reuseIdentifier` has not been set, the `UITableView` will be forced to allocate new `UITableViewCell` objects for each new item that scrolls into view, potentially leading to laggy animations.

Comment: yeah that's correct, A UITableView will normally allocate just enough UITableViewCell objects to display the content visible in the table.

Answer (score 7):

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/reuseIdentifier) says:

> The reuse identifier is associated with a UITableViewCell object that
>   the table-view’s delegate creates with the intent to reuse it as the
>   basis (for performance reasons) for multiple rows of a table view. It
>   is assigned to the cell object in initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: and
>   cannot be changed thereafter. A UITableView object maintains a queue
>   (or list) of the currently reusable cells, each with its own reuse
>   identifier, and makes them available to the delegate in the
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method.

reuseidentifier is an id from which you can get cell from it.

Answer (score 4):

As a cell scrolls out of the viewable area of the screen, the object representing it gets reused for cells scrolling on to the screen. The reuse identifier tells the system that an object can be reused for a cell entering the screen for which you request the same identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Reuse identifiers are required by UITableViewCell in order to support the dequeueing of reusable cells by uniquely identifying cell types. Normally you create a unique string reuse identifier for each kind of cell you have use.

refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/reuseIdentifier